# How to use imported from another program that has a main funciton?

Tags: python, class, import, program-entry-point

I am trying to organize my program better, and have decided to have small files that are imported into final.py.

Here I want DIrectorySetup to be initiated at the beginning of main. I want to be able to then call the directories.

This is what I tried:

```py
class DirectorySetup: 
    '''The directory paths for the program'''
    def __init__(self):

        self.cwd = os.getcwd()
        self.Raw_data_dir= self.cwd + '\Raw_data'
        self.Clean_data_dir= self.cwd + '\Clean_data'
        self.table_dir= self.cwd + '\Tables'

def main():                      # Define the main function
    #the class with the directory
    Directory= DirectorySetup()
    os.chdir(Directory.table_dir)

    ###does other things that I removed for clarity ###



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And then I run it in my final.py program:

```py
import INIT_SCTFT 
import os

first=INIT_SCTFT
first.main()
first.DirectorySetup.Clean_data_dir
```

That gives me the error

```py
   first.DirectorySetup.Clean_data_dir

AttributeError: type object 'DirectorySetup' has no attribute 'Clean_data_dir'
```

How do I get main() to save DirectorySetup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice:

You are importing module `INIT_SCTFT` and then assign `first` to this module.
Now first is a module (you can check by printing type(first).
`first.main()` will execute main function from `INIT_SCTFT`. All main is doing is creating an object and changing current dir. Then it ends.

Then `first.DirectorySetup.Clean_data_dir` try to call `Clean_data_dir` from class `DirectorySetup`. But class `DirectorySetup` does not have defined `Clean_data_dir`! An object of class `DirectorySetup` has this attribute. So if you want to get access to this attribute, you have to create an object first.

For example:

```
obj = first.DirectorySetup()
obj.Clean_data_dir
```

**EDIT:**

To answer your question from comment. It depends on what you want to achieve. For exapmle, you can create some method that will return a list of objects.

```
class DirectorySetup: 
'''The directory paths for the program'''
def __init__(self):

    self.cwd = os.getcwd()
    self.Raw_data_dir= self.cwd + '\Raw_data'
    self.Clean_data_dir= self.cwd + '\Clean_data'
    self.table_dir= self.cwd + '\Tables'


def create_objects():
    one = DirectorySetup()
    two = DirectorySetup()
    three = DirectorySetup()
    return one, two, three
```

Then in final.py you can create list of objects: `objects = first.create_objects()`
Or as you mentioned you can wrap it into some class:

```
class my_objects:
    one = DirectorySetup()
    two = DirectorySetup()
    three = DirectorySetup()
```

Then in final.py you access it by: `first.my_objects.one`. 
Also notice that if you decide to put objects in init:

```
class my_objects:
    def __init__():
        one = DirectorySetup()
        two = DirectorySetup()
        three = DirectorySetup()
```

Then first you will need to create an object of this class to get access to those variables `obj = first.my_objects()` then you can use it: `obj.one`.

Comment: So to get access to multiple objects, should I put all of them into a class and then call that, before executing main? 

like: 
<code>
class ALL: 
    def __init__(self):
       obj_a=DirectorysSetup()
       obj_b=Table()
<code>

and then do: 

oobject=first.ALL

Comment: I have edited my post to answer this question. Let me know if it is what you were looking for ;)

Answer (score 0):

How about you do it out of main?

DirectoryFile.py

```
class DirectorySetup: 
    '''The directory paths for the program'''
    def __init__(self):

        self.cwd = os.getcwd()
        self.Raw_data_dir= self.cwd + '\Raw_data'
        self.Clean_data_dir= self.cwd + '\Clean_data'
        self.table_dir= self.cwd + '\Tables'

#the class with the directory
Directory= DirectorySetup()
os.chdir(Directory.table_dir)
```

and then access `Directory` object from `final.py`

```
from DirectoryFile import Directory

#access variable Directory's member
print(Directory.Clean_data_dir)
```

The attribute only gets added into the object when **init**() is called which happens when an object is instantiated.

EDIT: On second thoughts, you could create a global variable out of main() which could go like this:

```
Directory = None

def main():
    global Directory
    Directory= DirectorySetup()
```

and then access it from `final.py`

Comment: In my original code, I dont only want to pull out just Directory, but also, a table etc. Doing all of them outside main kind of makes main less useful.
would you recommend writing my INIT_SCTFT without a main ?

Comment: Eventually `main()` is a method which can return only a limited number of variables. After the method exits, the variables are bound to be destroyed if not returned.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that python is garbage collecting your DirectorySetup instance after the function main has been called.

The simplest solution would be to have main just return the reference of the DirectorySetup instance so you can then access it:

```
def main():                      # Define the main function
#the class with the directory
Directory= DirectorySetup()
os.chdir(Directory.table_dir)
return Directory
###does other things that I removed for clarity ###
```

You would then just change your final.py script to:

```
import INIT_SCTFT 
import os

first=INIT_SCTFT
directory = first.main()
directory.Clean_data_dir
```

Comment: Thanks, 
this works. However I want to retrive more than just the Directory. 
My full main() also creates a table: 

 Table_1= first.features(init)

so I would have to either return both. I want something more flexible that allows me to call what I want as if it was part of a class